# Cannot rewrite PUT response body with apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, http

I'm writing a reverse proxy to a webapp.
I need to rewrite some of the webapp responses to match the public URL.
It works well for a GET api response ; but not for the PUT api response.
For PUT requests, the substitute rule is ignored.
Why ?

```
Define proxy_servername proxy.test
Define project_servername project.test:8080


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ${proxy_servername}
    ProxyPass / http://${project_servername}/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://${project_servername}/

    ProxyHTMLEnable on

    SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml

    ## Treat absolute url
    Substitute "s,http://${project_servername}/,http://${proxy_servername}/,i"

    RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
</VirtualHost>
```